# Visual Studio Refactor Hotkey?

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys

Is there any way to get this window with the keyboard?

[image]

I hate it to move my hands to the mouse and wait a "few" seconds that the window comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you search for ShowSmartTag command. Usually its

> Shift + Alt + F10

But you can customize it:

> Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard

[image: View.ShowSmartTag]

Comment: **THANK YOU SO MUCH!**
It was so anoying to use the mouse for these feature!